# setuptools sdist has appropriate files, wheel is missing top folder for packages

Tags: python, macos, setuptools

I'm trying to use the basic example from the [docs](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/index.html). I am able to successfully generate an sdist, but I want to be able to install from wheel. However, when installing from wheel instead of from the sdist, I don't have a `proj` directory that I can import, only `pkg1` and `pkg2`.

**Starting from this directory:**

```
├── proj
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── additional
│   │   └── __init__.py
│   ├── pkg1
│   │   └── __init__.py
│   └── pkg2
│       └── __init__.py
├── pyproject.toml
└── setup.cfg
```

**I tried using this setup.cfg:**

```
[metadata]
name = p1
version = 0.0.1

[options]
packages =
    find:
package_dir =
    =proj

[options.packages.find]
where = proj
include = pkg*
exclude = additional
```

**To generate this file structure, which is successfully generated in the source distribution:**

```
├── PKG-INFO
├── README.md
├── proj
│   ├── p1.egg-info
│   │   ├── PKG-INFO
│   │   ├── SOURCES.txt
│   │   ├── dependency_links.txt
│   │   └── top_level.txt
│   ├── pkg1
│   │   └── __init__.py
│   └── pkg2
│       └── __init__.py
├── pyproject.toml
└── setup.cfg
```

**But the wheel has this structure:**

```
├── p1-0.0.1.dist-info
│   ├── METADATA
│   ├── RECORD
│   ├── WHEEL
│   └── top_level.txt
├── pkg1
│   └── __init__.py
└── pkg2
    └── __init__.py
```

**This makes it impossible to use:**

```
import proj
```

As there is no such module, only modules `pkg1` and `pkg2`.

I made a repo for this here: https://github.com/spensmith/setuptools-find.

---

Steps to recreate:

1. Clone the base repository here: https://github.com/spensmith/setuptools-find
2. `cd setuptools-find`
3. `python -m build`
4. `mkdir dist/mywheel`
5. `unzip dist/p1-0.0.1-py3-none-any.whl -d dist/mywheel`
6. `tree dist/mywheel`

---

I must be missing something basic, any help would be so appreciated!

### Thank you, Spencer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My question was answered directly on the setuptools discussion forum. https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/discussions/3185#discussioncomment-2411330.

Effectively, I shouldn't be using

```
package_dir =
    =proj
```

Because this means that all of my code is within this folder. Instead, I should remove it entirely, and then change my exclude to look like:

```
[options.packages.find]
exclude = proj.additional
```

Finally, yielding this file:

```
[metadata]
name = p1
version = 0.0.1

[options]
packages =
    find:

[options.packages.find]
exclude = proj.additional
```